# github webhooks - how to detect additionally pushed commits on a pull request?

Tags: git, github

### Use case

Writing a bot, I want to cancel CI on every commit that will be pushed after creation of the PR.

### Question

Which webhook would give me the push events on the PR, ideally with all the PR information and which conditions of the returned objects must be set to detect the above reliably_

Comment: How is your CI triggered after any push is made? Does a git hook trigger it or Jenkins or bitbucket or something similar polls for changes?

Comment: That's not the issue really. I am running cloud function upon webhook and want to make subsequent decisions. I don't want CI to make those, because it's not what is there for.

Comment: What I was looking for is the event. I think I found it. It's `action: "synchronise"`